# How to turn TypeScript .min.js file generation on and off?

Tags: typescript, minify

With the TypeScript Visual Studio plugin, usually saving a .ts file causes 2 new files to be generated underneath of it: file.js and file.min.js.

Is there a way to configure this, so that you can turn off generation of the minified js?

Comment: Are you using Web Essentials? TypeScript itself won't generate .min.js files

Comment: That must be it, yes I do have web essentials installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use web essential 2012 ; it propose this capability

Answer (score 4):

In the latest release of Web Essentials, TypeScript support has been removed (see: http://vswebessentials.com/features/typescript). I noticed that when I add a TypeScript file now, I don't get the minified version anymore.

The main reason for this (as per the above article) is that the TypeScript extension will include many of the features itself.